# Set cell background color and text size using Google Java API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to set Spreadsheet cell background color and text size. I use this Java code to set the text into the cell but I can't find a solution how to set the style.

```
CellData setUserEnteredValue = new CellData()
            .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                .setStringValue("cell text"));
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't know if this works in Java, but you could try the method [setBackGround(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor), or you could use a [http request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#cellformat)

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Answer (score 7):

I had to go through allot of useless answers, but this worked for me. Here you go:

```
requests.add(new Request()
                .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                        .setCell(new CellData()
                                .setUserEnteredValue( new ExtendedValue().setStringValue("cell text"))
                                .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat()
                                        .setBackgroundColor(new Color()
                                                .setRed(Float.valueOf("1"))
                                                .setGreen(Float.valueOf("0"))
                                                .setBlue(Float.valueOf("0"))
                                        )
                                        .setTextFormat(new TextFormat()
                                                .setFontSize(15)
                                                .setBold(Boolean.TRUE)
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                        .setRange(new GridRange()
                                .setSheetId(sheetID)
                                .setStartRowIndex(1)
                                .setEndRowIndex(0)
                                .setStartColumnIndex(0)
                                .setEndColumnIndex(1)
                        )
                        .setFields("*")
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK this is not possible in the Java Spreadsheet API, you instead have to use the Apps Script;
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

From their documentation, [how to set the background](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String));

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D5");
range.setBackground("red");
```

and [how to set the font size](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontsizesize);

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
cell.setFontSize(20);
```

---

**Update**
[See flo5783's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458497/4781925), v4 now offers the ability to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a class designed exactly for this:
[CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellFormat.html)

In particular these following methods:

`public CellFormat setBackgroundColor(`[Color](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/Color.html)`backgroundColor)`

and

`public CellFormat setTextFormat(`[TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/TextFormat.html)`textFormat)`

I haven't coded in Java in ages so I won't try to give you a working code example, but I think you'll be able to figure it out easily from this.

**EDIT: Here's a basic example starting from your code:**

```
CellData setUserEnteredValue = new CellData()
            .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                .setStringValue("cell text"));

CellFormat myFormat = new CellFormat();
myFormat.setBackgroundColor(new Color().setRed(1)); // red background
myFormat.setTextFormat(new TextFormat().setFontSize(16)); // 16pt font

setUserEnteredValue.setUserEnteredFormat(myFormat);
```

Comment: I just added one below the **EDIT**, using the javadoc links I originally mentioned.

Comment: Please update the answer with setUserEnteredFormat. setEffectiveFormat is not working.

Comment: @PeterPenzov let me know if this works, and if so i'll update my answer with a 'read down'.

Comment: For the color to take effect you have to set "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor" on the UpdateCellsRequest fields, like this:
.setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")  OR .setFields("*")  to override all fields of the cell

Answer (score 1):

// For handling single cells this is how you do it, where j and k are row and columns in g sheet .

```
CellData setUserEnteredValue =new CellData()
                .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                        .setStringValue(maxs));
    List<CellData> values1.add(setUserEnteredValue);
        requests.add(new Request()
                .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
                        .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
                                .setRowIndex(j)
                                .setColumnIndex(k))
                        .setRows(Arrays.asList(
                                new RowData().setValues(values1)))
                        .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));
        

        CellFormat myFormat = new CellFormat();
        myFormat.setBackgroundColor(new Color().setRed(Float.valueOf("1"))); // red background
        setUserEnteredValue.setUserEnteredFormat(myFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the background color or the font size on a `CellData` object. You instead need to iterate over some cell ranges. From there, you can set the background color based on the cell value. You can then make your code dependable, like a 2-step process.
From another answer on SO:

```
//Sets the row color depending on the value in the "Status" column.
function setRowColors() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var statusColumnOffset = getStatusColumnOffset();

  for (var i = range.getRow(); i < range.getLastRow(); i++) {
    rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1); //Play with this range to get your desired columns.
    status = rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset).getValue(); //The text value we need to evaluate.
    if (status == 'Completed') {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#99CC99");
    } else if (status == 'In Progress') {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#FFDD88");    
    } else if (status == 'Not Started') {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#CC6666");          
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear.. Are you looking for something like this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting??

Comment: Yes, I want to make the same result using Java API v4

Comment: Well, from here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor it seems most of it is the same except for the initial 2 lines:   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];