# Q: How to format cell text in google sheets API using java?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Specifically, I was wondering how you can change the size, centering, and font color of a text inside a cell of a sheet.

What kind of request do I need to make? If someone can point me in the right direction of the API Documentation or give an example, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Create a [json request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#cellformat)  and send the json thus made using the [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate)

Comment: I answered to this question here. I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366503/4529455